# Angular.js filter premade html element

Tags: html-lists, angularjs

I was playing with angular.js the other day and I found this filter function, that angular.js provides for us.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
      <!--Sidebar content-->

      Search: <input ng-model="query">

    </div>
    <div class="span10">
      <!--Body content-->

      <ul class="phones">
        <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query">
          {{phone.name}}
          <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is: **Can I use angular.js filter on premade html elements**, somehing like this.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
      <!--Sidebar content-->

      Search: <input ng-model="query">

    </div>
    <div class="span10">
      <!--Body content-->

      <ul class="phones" ng-filter:query>
        <li>First element</li>
        <li>Second elementy/li>
        <li>Third element</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of DOM manipulation/filtering, Angular directives [ngSwitch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) or [ngShow](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow)/[ngHide](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angHide) are normally used.

```
<ul class="phones" ng-switch on="query">
<li ng-switch-when="Nexus S">First element</li>
```

The above would look for an exact match though (so it is not as nice as @tosh's directive).  ng-switch is often used with a select drop-down, where the possible values are fixed/known.

ngShow/ngHide are probably a better match for what you are trying to do.  An in-line expression or $scope function can be used to determine whether to show an element:

```
<li ngShow="some expression using query">First element</li>
<li ngShow="myFilter()">First element</li>

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.myFilter = function() {
       if($scope.query ...) {  // could use RegExp() here like @tosh
          return true
       }
       return false
    }
```

The above does not require jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

No. Your first example uses a *filter* - called "filter"! A *filter* can form part of an Angular binding expression. It is placed after a pipe character, and applies a "filter function" to the part of the expression that came before the pipe. Some filters also take additional parameters, to the right of a colon. The *filter* called "filter" acts on an Array (the part before the pipe, in this case *phones*) passing each item through a check determined by the parameter to the right of the colon. In your case, using a string variable called query, it returns an Array with any items from *phones* that contain the string in query.

Other examples of *filters* in Angular include currency, date, uppercase and orderBy. They all take an input (for example a string) returning another value (for example the uppercase version of the string) and in some cases additional configuration parameters (such as a date or currency format, or field to order by). But they only work with an input that is some value in the "data model", not directly on the content of a DOM node.

Your second example attempts to use a *directive* called "ngFilter". A *directive* is an extension to standard HTML syntax, and can be expressed as hyphenated attributes (as in this case), data- attributes (data-ng-filter), namespaced attributes (ng:filter), css classes, etc. Angular's default *directives* have the prefix "ng". But there is no such *directive* as "ngFilter" in Angular. Your example will load fine, but there will be no effect on the DOM processing from adding this non-existent directive.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that is part of the default directive, but
that's interesting task.

I tried to implement with a custom directive.  http://plnkr.co/edit/TOGbtq

```
app.directive('ngFilter', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.$watch(attr.ngFilter, function(q){
        $(element).children().each(function(i,a){
          $(a).toggle((new RegExp(q)).test($(a).text()));
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```